# How to handle a day that starts from 06:00 and ends at 30:00

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, c#-4.0

I am working with a case where the client has a 30 hour day.

The day starts at 6 am and then goes around to 6 am the next day, but when they come to 1 am the next day, they take it as 25:00 hours. 2 am will be 26:00 hours and so forth...

Now, i want to know, is there a way to handle this in `c#'s DateTime class` or do i need to do it the long way and split it all up?

**UPDATE**:

It's a Media Agency in Australia. Just to explain again, the day starts at `06:00 am (12 Jan 2012)`, when it comes to midnight it will be 24:00. Now when it is `01:00 am (13 Jan 2012)` the next day, the client takes it as `25:00 hours (12 Jan 2012)`.

They still have 24 hours in a day. The only difference is that their day starts at 6 am and not 00 hours like us.

**UPDATE:**

XML representation of a typical program i need to work with.
Note: Removed CHANNEL_CODE and CHANNEL_NAME.

```
 <PROGRAMME>
  <PROGRAMME_ID>1</PROGRAMME_ID>
  <PROGRAMME_NAME>Mass For You At Home</PROGRAMME_NAME>
  <CHANNEL_CODE>SomeCode</CHANNEL_CODE>
  <CHANNEL_NAME>SomeChannel</CHANNEL_NAME>
  <TX_DATE>20120101</TX_DATE>
  <START_TIME>06:00</START_TIME>
  <DURATION>1800</DURATION>
  <AGENCY_AVAIL>C</AGENCY_AVAIL>
  <SALES_AVAIL>90</SALES_AVAIL>
  <SSB>N</SSB>
 </PROGRAMME>
</PROGRAMME>


<PROGRAMME>
  <PROGRAMME_ID>2</PROGRAMME_ID>
  <PROGRAMME_NAME>Home Shopping</PROGRAMME_NAME>
  <CHANNEL_CODE>SomeCode</CHANNEL_CODE>
  <CHANNEL_NAME>SomeChannel</CHANNEL_NAME>
  <TX_DATE>20120101</TX_DATE>
  <START_TIME>26:00</START_TIME>
  <DURATION>1800</DURATION>
  <AGENCY_AVAIL>C</AGENCY_AVAIL>
  <SALES_AVAIL>0</SALES_AVAIL>
  <SSB>N</SSB>
 </PROGRAMME>
```

**So, is there maybe a way to adjust the `DateTime` class to start at 06:00 and end at 30:00?**

Comment: "where the client has a 30 hour day" - that seems ....bonkers!

Comment: I propose they are called `d30`s or `crazy-days`

Comment: Besides the bonkers part, I don't understand why `1 am the next day` would be 25 hours when 24 hours is 6 am.

Comment: It's a Media Agency in Australia. Just to explain again, the day starts at `06:00 am (12 Jan 2012)`, when it comes to midnight it will be 24:00. Now when it is `01:00 am (13 Jan 2012)` the next day, the client takes it as `25:00 hours (12 Jan 2012)`.

Comment: So..it's not from 0 to 24, but from 6 to 30?

Comment: what benefit do they get from the crazy 30 hour day? Or is this just for reporting purposes?

Comment: @MitchWheat It's just how the Media Industry works in Aus.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that one day is shorter than the others? Unless they work Sunday? They certainly can't work every day, unless they have 'crazy' weeks. You'd be better off calling these shifts, as referring to them as days is very confusing! Are you sure it's not because they are covering multiple timezones? In which case you could have shifts which relate to timezones which relate to dates. You'd then report on shift.startdate to eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: @Willem Then you don't have to adjust DateTime's behaviour. As Piotr already answered you just have to create proper display string.

Comment: @MitchWheat Like i said, it's how the Media Industry works. The employees still works a normal day, but when it comes to Adverts that needs to be shown on TV, that's how they work.

Comment: I think you really want something like a timeslot. This has a startdate and a length and should answer most of the questions you would need to ask it quite easily.

Comment: Please change the title of this question, apparently the days are not 30 hours but have an offset.

Comment: With the example that you've given, can't you just write `String.Format("{0:00}:{1:mm}", dt.Hours + 6, dt)` when you're generating your XML?

Comment: @AdeStringer Generating, no problem. The problems comes where i read the dates and then work with them in the system.

Comment: For that, I guess you'll just have to parse the time manually and subtract six hours when feeding the values into a `DateTime`.

Comment: What you want is for datetimes 00:00:00 to 05:59:59 of the current date to be displayed as 24:00:00 to 29:59:59 of the previous date. This is simply a formatting issue when displaying them. Store them as normal datetimes, and format them as such when displaying them. Of course you also need to parse them correctly, but you should still store them as normal datetimes.

Comment: This isn't really a 30 hour day, since it doesn't include 0 through 5 of the same day. It's just a _different_ 24 hours. Do you need to display 30:00:00, or just go from 29:59:59 to [next] 06:00:00?

Comment: @Random832 just go from 29:59:59 to [next] 06:00:00

Comment: what you want is to just add 6 hours to whatever the hour is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sounds a bit like the situation where you have a business that covers multiple timezones - it's possible, then, to have a continuous day that is longer than 24 hours.

However, this doesn't mean that you have to adjust the length of a day - a day is an international convention, and, unless Jon Skeet actually decides to use the giant gravity gun he has undoubedly built (in a day ;-) and uses it to change the rotational speed of the earth, extending the alternating period of light and darkness we refer to as a day, your best bet is to probably use the concept of a shift or timeslot;

A shift (in your case, a timeslot!) has a work day, a length, and a timezone. You can then:

- Sum all of the hours an advert was shown for a workday (sum[length] where date = workday)
- Sum all of the hours an advert was shown for a timezone (sum[length] where timezone = x group by workday
- Sum all of the hours an advert was on for a particular astronomical date (work out the number of hours between the workday.starttime and midnight versus the length)

It's best not to refer to these as days as it confuses straightforward terminology.

In your instance, you aren't even bothered about the timezone. I think all you really need is the date/time the advert timeslot is due to start, and the number of hours it is due to be shown for.

EDIT: In the case of your XML, you can still use the above concept. You can either:

1) Clean it up when you get the XML and store it as a 'proper' datetime - so work out what the UTC starttime is and use the duration

2) Create a class that just converts this to normal datetime representation with the length.  The benefit of this approach is that you can also go the other way, back to the source convention.

Realistically, I think that's really all you need.

For example, in the xml above, you could create a class; something like this should do the trick:

```
public class AdvertDate{

    public DateTime TransmissionDate { get; set;} //Store as 06:00 on the TX_Date

    public int AdvertStartTime { get; set; } //Store as 0 - 30

    public int Duration { get; set; } //Store as 18 - assuming whole numbers so change if needed        
    public DateTime RealDate {
        get{
            return TransmissionDate.AddHours(AdvertStartTime);
        }
    }


    public AdvertDate(){

    }

    public AdvertDate(DateTime transmissionDate, int advertStartTime, int duration){
        TransmissionDate = transmissionDate;
        AdvertStartTime = advertStartTime;
        Duration = duration;
    }


    public AdvertDate ConvertRealDateTimeToAdvertDate(DateTime realDateTime, int advertDuration){

        if(realDateTime.Hour < 6)
        {
            DateTime  advertDateTime = realDateTime.AddDays(-1).Date.AddHours(6);

            return new AdvertDate(advertDateTime, 24+realDateTime.Hour, advertDuration);
        }
        else{
            return new AdvertDate(realDateTime.Date.AddHours(6), realDateTime.Hour, advertDuration);
        }

    }


    public void LoadFromXml(){
        //Xml Loading here (or in a dedicated class or wherever)
    }



}
```

Comment: Perfect. You seem to understand dash. My problem is, that all their DateTime value's are from `6000 to 3000 hours`. So i don't want to make display strings every time when importing `xml`, exporting and so forth... I just want a easier way to work with their "Timespan"

Comment: Just to clear something up - for the advert on date 20120101 that starts at 26:00 - is that actually 08:00 of 20120101 (6AM of the previous day +26) or is it 20120102 at 02:00?

Comment: The next thing to do then is to decide on how they want to report on this. Do they want to report on transmission date 20120101? Do they want to report on actual date (20120102). If you store the tx date and have another property - realdate - that moves back and forward between the two (which is just new datetime(2012, 1, 1, 6, 0, 0).AddHours(StartTime) you should be able to do both.

Comment: Works good and say i want to work from 3000 hours timespan to realtime? How would u go about that. Combinding the TX_DATE + START_TIME will not Parse() if u got `20120101 26:00`. What do you suggest?

Comment: Don't bother - TX_Date is one argument, and just convert advert start time to a number between 0 and 26, and feed them into the AdvertDate constructor. It should take care of the rest.

Comment: From your comments here, I'm a bit confused about the hour cut offs. If an advert were to start at 20120101 23:00 in your system, what time in reality would it be? If ct(20120101 26:00) == rt(20120102 02:00) then it would mean you don't have 30 hours in a day, but 24, just shifted up 6! *ct = crazy time, rt = real time

Comment: I took this as meaning the following; A day as far as an advert is concerned is a maximum of 30hours; if I schedule an advert for the 1st Jan it can actually be shown up to 6AM of the following day - hence the original 30 hours question. If the OP finds he wants to measure his day from a different offset, he should just be able to change the AddHours(6) to be whatever his offset is. I think. What day is it again?

Comment: You are correct. ct(20120101 26:00) == rt(20120102 02:00). I explained it pretty bad tho. So is there something else that i can use?

Comment: It's very common in some other industries (for example, how power is sold in the UK) to have hours 24 through 26 to represent the previous day, so you aren't alone :-) The important thing is to encapsulate this logic somewhere so that way, if you change your day convention, or need others, you have one place where you can do this.

Answer (score 7):

Always store your data in some universal standard format and treat any other requirements as display/output formatting only.

When dealing with date/times that originate from different timezones (different to the server or also between clients), it is best to store them using the [C# DateTimeOffset structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) along with the [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) field type of SQL Server 2008 R2.

This gives you the power to determine not just "universal time", but also to know what the times are *relative to any given client*.

*You have not stated the actual uses for the 30 hour days, so I can't provide specifics without more information, but as stated by others you would need to provide a custom class for your funky date output.*

Comment: Back to my first point... *Always store your data in some universal standard format*... convert to DateTimeOffsets on loading the XML... Convert back for display if needed. *Remember the Mars mission that failed because it used Miles Per Hour instead of SI units?* :)

Comment: The actual use seems to be a scheduling thing - if the station signs off in the early morning hours (4 or so) and then signs on at 6, then keeping the whole broadcast day in one written date makes sense.

Comment: @Random832: In my experience, if you use a custom format for the internal storage of data more errors and mistakes will creep in. You need something you can always trust. Keeping the core data in a *standard* format reduces those errors. 7 years ago I had to write a railway yard management system with 25 hours days on leap years and wish I had the DateTimeOffset objects back then! :)

Answer (score 4):

Since the extended days overlap, some operations you could achieve with `DateTime` but at the time you introduce this 30 hour day you also need to answer a lot of question and introduce concepts of the operations and rules of those days.

You will almost certainly need to create your own type for handling this.  If nothing else, you'll need to convert actual days (`DateTime` can handle in *most* cases though I wouldn't be surprised if J.S. posts about his superior library/framework) to/from "crazy-days".

For example: you really have to spec out all the operations, and answer these questions:

- How many days are there between crazy-date 12 Jan 2012 and crazy-date 20 Jan 2012?
- How many crazy-days are there between normal date 12 Jan 2012 and normal date 20 Jan 2012?
- How many hours are there between crazy-dates 12 Jan 2012 and 13 Jan 2012?  Or 12 Jan 2012 and 14 Jan 2012?

All of those could have different answers and are not obvious.  You'd have to spec/work it out with the client, depending on what the use case or end use, or output of the process(es) you are designing.

Comment: Yes, it does. I was merely pointing out that the requirements should examine whether any special handling is required for leap adjustments...

Comment: Ah I see, you're adding that point.  Glad I'm not going crazy.  Let me tidy up my comments..

Comment: Okay i think i might have explained that they have actual 30 hours in a day. Sorry about that. They still have 24 hours in a day, but they only start there day at 6 am... So is there a way that i can adjust the `DateTime` class accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

I can see no way of 'adjusting' the DateTime class for a scenario like this.

All calculations in the class will be different. You could roll your own DateTime by copying/learning from the sources of DateTime.

NB: I'd make very sure I'd need this, it sounds a bit wrong

Comment: So your question is wrong. the days are not 30 hours, they start at an offset. I'd use the offset in the client and use proper UTC times in databases and such.

Comment: If one would go for copying, surely one would go for subclassing, wouldn't we?

Comment: @cfi - when you subclass (in case it is a 30hrs day) there is a danger that someone decides to pass a SpecialDateTime to a method that expects a Datetime. You need to be able to state that a SpecialDateTime IS a DateTime and I am not so sure that that is right.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will be ok if you keep standard dates but display them with convention of your client.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so it's not a thirty hour day, but a 24 hour day offset from your local time by six hours.  It sounds like you ought to be using `DateTimeOffset`:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012, 2, 12, 8, 34, 56); 
var dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, TimeSpan.FromHours(-6));
```

You'll need to be using .Net 3.5 in order to be able to use the `DateTimeOffset` structure.  Note that you'll have to have a `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` in order to be able to feed it into the `DateTimeOffset` constructor with any offset - for instance, if you have `DateTimeKind.Utc` then your offset must be zero.

Answer (score 2):

When importing the data just add 1 day when the hour is greater than 24 and then subtract 24 from the hour.

to convert back the other way:

```
public static void DateTimeTo30HourDay(DateTime tx_datetime)
{
    if (tx_datetime.Hour < 6)
    {
        // subtract one day
        tx_datetime = tx_datetime.AddDays(-1);
    }
    int offsetHours = tx_datetime.Hour + 6;

    string tx_date = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", tx_datetime.Year.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'), tx_datetime.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), tx_datetime.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
    string start_time = string.Format("{0}:{1}", offsetHours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), tx_datetime.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));

    // do what you want here
}
```

That's basically all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a DateTime typed baseDate variable.
When it's time for it, set it to current date `baseDate = DateTime.Date.AddHours(6)`;
When displaying a time use a TimeSpan as:

```
TimeSpan ts = specifiedDateTime - Globals.baseDate;
string text = string.Format("{0:yyyy.MM.dd} {1:00}:{2:00}", Globals.baseDate, Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes);
```

Display the text variable;